# Proof all the second order characters were Legendre (Argument without using cyclic group)

Tags: number-theory, characters

1. the group of characters was a cyclic group of order $p-1$.
2. Legendre symbol was a character of order $2$.

Thus by the uniqueness of the order $2$ elements in cyclic group, all second order characters were Legendre.

However, I was wondering if there was any other way to prove it.
For example, prove it without the knowledge of the first statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p$ be an odd prime.
Consider the multiplicative group $G=\Bbb F_p^\times$. The map $s:G\to G$
defined by $s(a)=a^2$ is a homomorphism with kernel $\{\pm1\}$. Its image
$s(G)$ therefore has order $|G|/2=(p-1)/2$. Any character $\chi:G\to\{\pm1\}$ must be trivial on $s(G)$ as that consists of squares.
Thus $\chi$ factors through $G\mapsto G/s(G)$ and as $|G/s(G)|$
has order $2$, there is only one character of order $2$ on $G$.
This must be the Legendre symbol.